# Redux + Angular : How to simplify usage combineLatest & Latest from?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, es6-promise

I'm trying to get values pointing to tokenExpiration value from Store after app start. Because these values are filled in the async way I added check suing filter function to receive not null values.

During testing, I found that new value have to be fetched using withLatestFrom because combineLatest returns old value from first not null data fetch occurence. The solution described below is working but seems to be a little bit complicated so I would like to ask how to simplify with usage only **combineLatest** OR **withLatestFrom** (or different way).

Thanks for any advice.

```
  @Effect({ dispatch: false, resubscribeOnError: true })
    // Use combineLatest to get value from the mutliple sources & avoid to getting null values using filter option
    setProperSection$ = combineLatest([
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(AuthPatientActions.setProperSection)
        ),
        this.store.pipe(select(selectTokenExpiration), filter(t => !!t), take(1)),
        this.store.pipe(select(selectTenant), filter(t => !!t), take(1)),
    ]).pipe(
        // In order to get fresh values from store is need to get values using withLatestFrom
        // because the combineLatest holds the old values in the memory (given by filter option)
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectTokenExpiration))),
        mergeMap(async a => {
            await this.notificationSvc.showPreloader();
            return a;
        }),
        mergeMap(async ([a, tokenExpiration]) => {
                const nowDt = new Date();
                const tokenExpDt = new Date(tokenExpiration);
                if (nowDt >= tokenExpDt) {
                    this.notificationSvc.showToast(this.translateSvc.instant("SESSION_ENDED_PLEASE_LOGIN"));
                    this.router.navigate(["login"], {}).catch(reason => {
                        console.error(reason);
                    });
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(["dashboard"], {}).catch(reason => {
                        this.notificationSvc.showToast(this.translateSvc.instant("CANNOT_NAVIGATE_TO_GIVEN_SECTION"));
                    });
                }
                return AuthPatientActions.doRedirect();
            }
        ),
        mergeMap(async a => {
            await this.notificationSvc.hidePreloader();
            return a;
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to combine them you're taking 1 from the stream and then closing it with take(1). Try this:

```
    setProperSection$ = combineLatest([
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(AuthPatientActions.setProperSection)
        ),
        this.store.pipe(select(selectTokenExpiration), filter(t => !!t)),
        this.store.pipe(select(selectTenant), filter(t => !!t)),
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mergeMap(async a => {
            await this.notificationSvc.showPreloader();
            return a;
        }),
```

Besides your actual question, you should consider instead above:

```
delayWhen(async a => await this.notificationSvc.showPreloader()),
```

After all that should work:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false, resubscribeOnError: true })
setProperSection$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<AddUser>(AddUserActionTypes.AddUser),
    delayWhen(async action => await this.notificationSvc.showPreloader()),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectTokenExpiration))),
    map(([, tokenExpiration]) => tokenExpiration), // remove the action param
    mergeMap(async tokenExpiration => {
            const nowDt = new Date();
            const tokenExpDt = new Date(tokenExpiration);
            if (nowDt >= tokenExpDt) {
                this.notificationSvc.showToast(this.translateSvc.instant("SESSION_ENDED_PLEASE_LOGIN"));
                this.router.navigate(["login"], {}).catch(reason => {
                    console.error(reason);
                });
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(["dashboard"], {}).catch(reason => {
                    this.notificationSvc.showToast(this.translateSvc.instant("CANNOT_NAVIGATE_TO_GIVEN_SECTION"));
                });
            }
            return AuthPatientActions.doRedirect();
        }
    ),
    delayWhen(async r => await this.notificationSvc.hidePreloader()),
}
```